# How much cpu usage is too much

Tags: android, memory, cpu-usage

I'm almost done with an app and I noticed that it runs at about 6-12% cpu when its in the background.  Is this too much?  What's a good amount our does it mostly depend on the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend on the application. 6-12% CPU would be too much for a software like text editor. But it would not be too much for a web crawler and indexer crawling and indexing the web through 30 threads.

Whether it is too much or not also depends on the nature of other processes running on the system. While 6-12% CPU usage may not be threatening to other processes running on the system, but in case you are running a CPU intensive task say, sorting gigabytes of data that you need very urgently or indexing the web, you would want the CPU usage to go as high as 80% or even more and as a result you wouldn't want to run any other CPU intensive process on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned that you may be doing some wasteful operation without realizing it, you may want to use the [profiler](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to see if you are spending too much time in code that you shouldn't. It may also be the case that your app requires 6-12% CPU for what it does, which shouldn't a problem if it's actually putting it to good use.